# Is it possible to embed Python 2 and Python 3 at the same executable or choose between them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, software-distribution

I have the following situation

- Python is embedded inside C++ application.
- Difference between Python 2 and 3 APIs are guarded using Macros (I check `PY_VERSION_MAJOR`)
- A Set of APIs are written and generated using Python scripts, then compiled into shared objects using Cython.
- I noticed that `python-config` generates linker options against the major and minor version (ex. `-lpython2.7`)

The current way I support Python 2 and 3, that I generate different executable and shared objects (c extensions) for each version.

Is there a way to support Python 2 and 3 at the same time within the same executable without providing two copies of the executable and shared objects ?

Comment: It seems unlikely. I would imagine you'll have a tonne of symbol name conflicts.

Comment: possible? maybe, but likely a huge headache

Comment: One possibility is to write an interface that is ambivalent between python2/python3, write separate shared libraries one for python2 and one for python3 that both conform to this interface, then have the main executable choose which to load at runtime. You still have multiple shared libraries, but just one executable.

Comment: @JMAA, this looks too tedious. I believe I have to maintain this interface and update it for each function I'd use. am I right ?

Comment: Yes, unless you can think of a cleverer workaround. Based on the limited information you've given, this may be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe reconsider why you need to support python2 and python3 simultaneously with interpreters in the same application? Can you just upgrade everything to python3? Can you call python interpreters as spawned subprocesses?

Comment: @JIMAA, Well I work in a big enterprise, and they claim they support specific versions of redhat, suse and centos, and I have to support every python version on these versions of these distributions. 
I have to support 3 versions : 2.6, 2.7 and 3.
I have already done that but with 3 different copies, and narrowed the scope of the question.